# LandScape Orientation on iPhone Not Work Correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, xcode6

recently i develop an application using swift in xcode 6.3.
application support iPhone and iPad in landscape Mode (Both Right and Left)
i have set the

> supported Interface Orientation

[image: info.pList Screenshot]
in info.plist to landscapeRight and Left for ipad,iphone and universal
in iPad its work Correctly but in iPhone just one Landscape mode Work and dont change when Rotating Device
also i add this to appDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int
    {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape.rawValue)
    }
```

but not work
and adding the code to root ViewController

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool
    {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int
    {

        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight.rawValue | UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft.rawValue)
    }

    override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight
    }
```

but dont work either
any body know whats going on in iPhone?
tnx for adv

Answer (score 0):

1. In the Project Navigator select your project
2. Tap your target in the target list
3. Select the "General" tab

You will find the "Landscape Left" and "Landscape Right" checkboxes in the Deployment Info section

[image]

Comment: i do this, but not work !! i say that the config exist in .plist

Comment: Are you testing it on the simulator or on an actual device? Your code is correct and it should work as expected on a device. Often times the simulator does not handle orientation changes correctly. Perform a "Clean" and run it on a device

Comment: test on device, iphone 5s and 4s. it just pick the first item from info.plist option, if i change the order of supported Interface Orientation options and build. its change on start

Comment: You could try deleting those values from info.plist and set them in the "Deployment Info" suggested above.